# Использование методов внутри функции

Tags: javascript, методы, функции

Здравствуйте!
Я пытаюсь сделать ползунок для проигрывателя, но проблема в том, что при создании объекта `audio` я не могу вызвать метод внутри функции и приходиться вызывать два раза `setInterval`. Скажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как-то это исправить?

То есть приходится делать так:

```
var audio = new Audio();
setInterval("var a = Math.floor(audio.currentTime / (audio.duration / 200))", 500);
setInterval(function(){
    $('#timeline').css({"width" : "" + a + "px"});
}, 500);
```

Вместо того, чтобы сделать так:

```
var audio = new Audio();
setInterval(function(){
    var a = Math.floor(audio.currentTime / (audio.duration / 200));
    $('#timeline').css({"width" : "" + a + "px"});
}, 500);
```

Comment: какой осмысленный заголовок вопроса...

ну да ладно, а почему собственно второй код у вас не работает?

Comment: Вот именно я не знаю. )))
Я подумал что наверное нельзя использовать методы обьектов которые были созданы за пределами функции

Comment: а консоль что-нибудь подсказывает?

Comment: window.onload? $(function(){})? не, не слышал

Comment: Нет не слышал и что с этим делать?

Answer (score 1):

А если сделать так (чтобы в одном замыкании было):

```
(function(){

var audio = new Audio();
setInterval(function(){
    var a = Math.floor(audio.currentTime / (audio.duration / 200));
    $('#timeline').css({"width" : "" + a + "px"});
}, 500);

}());
```

Comment: Чёто тоже не срабатывает.